# wpf - how to support bitmap transparency in imagebrush

Tags: wpf

I have a lot of pre-existing BMPs (and our clients have pre-existing bmps as well) that prevent us from simply converting them to PNGs.  How does one get WPF to respond to the transparency techniques formerly used in winforms?

Thanks,
jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these folks have "answered" your question:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/bb81d488-5b9b-4737-8b74-1476f843a717

Looks like it's possible, but takes a little bit of work and isn't available "out of the box."

Comment: Very nice. This and the associated links are exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.